# Check if the nested directory structure is empty using perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

My requirement is to check if a nested directory structure is having any binary file or not.

The directory structure looks something like this:

```
DIR-A
    |
    |--DIR-X
    |       |
    |       |--DIR-X1
    |       |--DIR-X2
    |
    |--DIR-Y
    |       |
    |       |--DIR-Y1
    |       |--DIR-Y2
    |       |--DIR-Y3
    |
    |--DIR-Z
    |       |
    |       |--DIR-Z1
    |       |--DIR-Z2
    |       |--DIR-Z3
```

At any point in time there can be more directories at Level-1 or Level-2 i.e. there can be some more directories i.e. `DIR-P, DIR-Q` etc at level-1 and there can be `DIR-X3 or DIR-Y4` at level-2.

I have written a sample code but it exits if it finds `DIR-X1`, Ideally it should exit if there is a binary file inside the directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $someDir = "/path/of/DIR-A";
my @files = ();
my $file;
my $i=0;

opendir(DIR, "$someDir") or die "Cant open $someDir: $!\n";
    @files = readdir(DIR);
    foreach $file(@files) 
    {
          unless ($file =~ /^[.][.]?\z/) 
        {
            print "$i : $file \n";              
            $i++;
            last;
            }
        }

    if ($i != 0) 
    {
        print "The directory contains files! \n";
        exit 1;      
    } 
    else 
    {
        print "This DIR-A is Empty! \n";
        exit 0;
    }

closedir(DIR);
```

Please suggest me get to the expected solution as below:

```
read DIR-A
print SUCCESS, if none of the nested directories have a binary file.
print ERROR, if at least one of the nested directories has a binary file.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could do with some clarification as to how you identify a 'binary file' - is it by extension, or do you need to do some content inspection?

Comment: @Sobrique: The binary files could be *.h, *.bin or *.c files.

Comment: `*.h` and `*.c` aren't typically 'binary' - they're usually ascii text pre-compilation.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I had called it "binary" just for the sake of simplicity here. However in the real usecase, the nested directories may have a *.x, *.h or *.bin files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $someDir = "/path/of/DIR-A";

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name('*.bin')
                            ->in($someDir);
```

This will get you all files with the extension '.bin'.

If you need to perform a per file test to check that they are 'binary' then you can use `grep` on your list of `@files`.

```
my @files = grep {-B} File::Find::Rule->file()
                                      ->in($someDir);

print "Binary files found\n" if @files;
```

Also:

- `use strict;` `use warnings;`. It's good.
- Code formatting is a really good thing. `perltidy -pbp` makes it easy.

Answer (score 1):

I am unclear as to what a binary file is for your test. I am assuming that any file found in the directory structure traversed is a binary file. Using [`File::Find`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html), which is a core module:

```
use File::Find;

my $error = 0;
find(\&wanted, @ARGV);

if( $error ) {
  print "ERROR, $error files found\n";
}
else {
  print "SUCCESS\n";
}

sub wanted {
  if( -f $_ ) {
    $error++;
  }
}
```

You may add any test to the `wanted` function. The `find` function will invoke the function provided for each file found in the list of directories that is also passed, which will be traversed recursively in depth-first search order (much like the `find` command does.) Passing it `@ARGV` you may invoke the script with a list of directories as required (maybe using shell expansion like `DIR-*`.)

The test function will get the file name being traversed in `$_`, while the current working directory is set to the directory that contains the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to find if binary file exist or not recursively.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

my $path="/path/of/DIR-A";

sub find_binary {
    my $file = $File::Find::name;

    if (-B $file && ! -d $file) {
        print "ERROR: At least one of the nested directories has a binary file : $file\n";
        exit;
    }
}

find(\&find_binary,$path);
print("SUCCESS: None of the nested directories have a binary file. \n");
```

Comment: Hi @nakulbansal : In either case (whether or not a binary is present) i'm getting the SUCCESS message. I think the code needs a  bit of fine tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Use (warning: my) module `File::Globstar`:

```
use v5.10;
use File::Globstar qw(globstar);

my $dir = $ARGV[0] // '.';
say join "\n", grep { -B && ! -d } globstar "$dir/**";
```

If you want the list of files in a list, assign it instead of printing it:

```
my @nondirs = grep { -B && ! -d } globstar "$dir/**";
```

If you know the extender of the files, you can also do this:

```
my @nondirs = grep { -B && ! -d } globstar "$dir/**/*.png";
```

Note that the file test `-B` produces a truthy value for empty files which is maybe not what you want.  In that case change the test to `-B && -s && ! -d`.